# Copy files to application documents directory to iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Is there some easy way to copy files to simulate iTunes file sharing in the simulator?

At this moment I print the directory name from the simulator, find out it's something like `/Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/720B1124-F678-442A-9A1F-58A03736ABA8/Documents` and copy files there in my favourite file manager.

Is there some Xcode tool that can automate this for deployment for different simulators or computers?